# Calculating delta time from a log file using python

Tags: python, extract

I am stuck on trying to find delta of the first and last time stamp from a log file

Here is a section of the log file

```
[2020-07-31 15:49:22,015][SRC.Env][I]:Reading 
[2020-07-31 15:49:22,015][SRC.Env][I]:Finished Initilization 
[2020-07-31 15:49:22,052][SRC][I]:Creating link
[2020-07-31 15:49:22,053][SRC][I]:Starting
.
.
.
[2020-08-03 09:17:29,351][SRC.Upload][I]:Finished
```

The following is what I have done thus far

```
import re
from dateutil import parser

with open('run.log') as run_log:
  times = [re.findall(r'\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2} \d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2},\d{3}',
      line) for line in run_log.readlines() if 'SRC' in line]
print(times)

time_delta = parser.parse(times[-1]) - parser.parse(times[0])
print(time_delta)
```

When I print times, it seemed to show all the times (as expected) `[['2020-07-31 15:49:22,011'], ['2020-07-31 15:49:22,015'],...['2020-08-03 09:17:29,351']]`

However, when I am trying to substract the first time to the last time, I recieve the following error

```
    return DEFAULTPARSER.parse(timestr, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Shared\Python36_64\lib\site-packages\dateutil\parser\_parser.py", line 646, in parse
    res, skipped_tokens = self._parse(timestr, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Shared\Python36_64\lib\site-packages\dateutil\parser\_parser.py", line 725, in _parse
    l = _timelex.split(timestr)         # Splits the timestr into tokens
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Shared\Python36_64\lib\site-packages\dateutil\parser\_parser.py", line 207, in split
    return list(cls(s))
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Shared\Python36_64\lib\site-packages\dateutil\parser\_parser.py", line 76, in __init__
    '{itype}'.format(itype=instream.__class__.__name__))
TypeError: Parser must be a string or character stream, not list
```

I decided to learn how to code about two months ago, so any assistance would really help in my progress. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is [re.findall()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.findall) returns a `list`.

You can access the single element using `re.findall(pattern, s)[0]`

```
import re
from dateutil import parser

with open('run.log') as run_log:
    times = [re.findall(r'\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2} \d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2},\d{3}',
                        line)[0] for line in run_log.readlines() if 'SRC' in line]
print(times)

time_delta = parser.parse(times[-1]) - parser.parse(times[0])
print(time_delta)
```

**Output:**

```
['2020-07-31 15:49:22,015', '2020-07-31 15:49:22,015', '2020-07-31 15:49:22,052', '2020-07-31 15:49:22,053', '2020-08-03 09:17:29,351']
2 days, 17:28:07.336000
```